# How to improve this question?

Tags: support

How to improve [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450081/does-m1-support-displayport2-0) question?

I have searched the web (Bing), there is no result for this topic.

Comment: I would imagine that the question asked is readily available at apple.com under specs for that particular Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the note you see on top of the question:

> Questions must **demonstrate a reasonable amount of research** & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) **clearly describe your problem and the research done so far** to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I'v read this, but what if there is no related reference online at all? Can "I'v tried, but no result" be one type of "reasonable amount of research"?

Comment: @iUnknown You still could show where you searched and what you found, both in regards to what Apple offers and the general availability of DisplayPort 2.0. It may also help to be a bit more specific, right now it's not clear whether you ask about the specific iPad, the availablility in any M1/M2 based Apple device, or the capability of the SoC as such. Also, which practical problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: I'v updated it, can you reopen it ?

Comment: @iUnknown If you ticked the checkbox to indicate that the edit addresses the reason the Q was on hold it gets placed into the review queue for reopenings automatically.